# capture output from java

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, arguments

I am trying to do that :

```
#!/bin/bash
set out=$(java -jar -Xmx1024m myJava.jar '$1' '$2' '$3' '$4')

echo "$out"
python myPython.py $out
```

but with no success... I tried with and without quote (because I args spaces)
My $out is still empty
When I do it in my prompt it works well :

```
$ out=$(java -jar -Xmx1024m ./myJava.jar "my first arg" "the second" "16/08/2018" "today")
$ echo $out 
0.0713471058122825407821210319525562226772308349609375;-0.113426821667920230130022218872909434139728546142578125;-0.07482244404633091316991766461796942166984081268310546875;-0.00013298701298701301443637434740452363257645629346370697021484375;-0.00013298701298701301443637434740452363257645629346370697021484375;0;0;-0.06257619772167842542298643593312590382993221282958984375;-0.0012893073228041856785608398894282800029031932353973388671875;-0.005419324847814057342920701643151915050111711025238037109375;-0.004168854454897620055719986709164004423655569553375244140625;-0.0490697081751974295560358996226568706333637237548828125;-0.186613852226874044060167534553329460322856903076171875;-0.07054484590055905279815107178364996798336505889892578125;0.050250353948686043992211125441826879978179931640625;0;-0.0373516921266305590432210692597436718642711639404296875;-0.2356835604020714736162034341759863309562206268310546875;-0.4285714285714286031492292750044725835323333740234375
```

I tried to

```
echo java -jar -Xmx1024m myJava.jar '$1' '$2' '$3' '$4'
```

and it looks good and works when I paste it in my prompt.

Is my bash script wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that `'$1'` will not expand the variable. Do you really intend to pass a literal dollar sign? If not, you should write `"$1"` in double quotes.

This is supported by your second example where you pass actual values and it works.